# Select values in a dataset if the threshold is above for every sample for that group

Tags: r, heatmap

I would like to generate a `heatmap` in R from a similar `dataframe`, keeping only the **"CLASS"** with **"VALUE"** above 0, but for every sample, so in this case discarding only CLASS **"D"**:

| CLASS | SAMPLE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 1 |
| B | X | 1 |
| C | X | 1 |
| D | X | 0 |
| A | Y | 1 |
| B | Y | 1 |
| C | Y | 0 |
| D | Y | 0 |
| A | Z | 1 |
| B | Z | 0 |
| C | Z | 0 |
| D | Z | 0 |

making then a dataframe like this:

| CLASS | SAMPLE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 1 |
| B | X | 1 |
| C | X | 1 |
| A | Y | 1 |
| B | Y | 1 |
| C | Y | 0 |
| A | Z | 1 |
| B | Z | 0 |
| C | Z | 0 |
| B | Z | 0 |
| C | Z | 0 |
| D | Z | 0 |

I've tried `filter(df, VALUE>0)`, but the generated heatmap presents empty squares

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with `any` after grouping by 'CLASS'

```
library(dplyr) #version >= 1.1.0
df1 %>% 
   filter(any(VALUE >0), .by = CLASS)
```

-output

```
   CLASS SAMPLE VALUE
1     A      X     1
2     B      X     1
3     C      X     1
4     A      Y     1
5     B      Y     1
6     C      Y     0
7     A      Z     1
8     B      Z     0
9     C      Z     0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(CLASS = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
"A", "B", "C", "D"), SAMPLE = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"), VALUE = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Using this method, I obtain the following error:

Error in `filter()`:
! We detected a named input.
ℹ This usually means that you've used `=` instead of `==`.
ℹ Did you mean `.by == CLASS`?
---
Backtrace:
 1. df1 %>% filter(any(VALUE > 0), .by = CLASS)
 3. dplyr:::filter.data.frame(., any(VALUE > 0), .by = CLASS)


where's the mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: @AndreaColautti you may have an older dplyr version.  Try `df1 %>% group_by(CLASS) %>% filter(any(VALUE >0)) %>% ungroup` for it to work on older dplyr

Comment: @AndreaColautti I think it is better to update your packages as old code can soon become deprecated.  It is probably good to have the most up-to-date code so that the code you create could work for a longer period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `ave` + `subset`

```
> subset(df,ave(VALUE, CLASS) > 0)
   CLASS SAMPLE VALUE
1      A      X     1
2      B      X     1
3      C      X     1
5      A      Y     1
6      B      Y     1
7      C      Y     0
9      A      Z     1
10     B      Z     0
11     C      Z     0
```